# How to turn extracted href into hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagging

I'm working on a tagging part on a site similar to Facebook. The idea is that whenever someone types @ in the post area, a drop down menu appears containing all of his friends. He then picks who he wants to tag and clicks on that person's profile. I have a javascript function which detects when @ is pressed, and then calls another js function which then in turn sends an ajax request to a php file for the list. And this part works great.

So when the user clicks on someone from their friend list, I set it up so that an href part containing the friend's username is extracted from the php file as plain text, and then displayed as a text string right after the @ character in the post area (I prevented following to the profile after clicking with `return: false`). So, for example, when someone wants to choose John Smith, he presses @, the list appears, he picks John Smith, clicks on his profile, the list disappears, and then the username appears after @, like this: @john_smith

Now the trouble is that I would want to make john_smith after @ into a hyperlink that would lead to John Smith's profile, instead of it being just plain text. And I've been really struggling to find a solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!  :)

```
**//php ajax file**

    <?php

    $userLoggedIn = $_POST['userLoggedIn'];

    $userLoggedIn = new User($con, $userLoggedIn);

    $rez = array();
    $rez = $userLoggedIn->getFriendArray();


    if ($rez != ",") {

    $no_commas = explode(",", $rez);

    foreach ($no_commas as $key => $value) {

        $friend = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT first_name, last_name, username, profile_pic FROM users WHERE username='$value'");

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($friend);

         echo "<div class='displayTag'>

                        <a href=" . $row['username'] . " id='grabLink'>         

                            <div>
                                <img src='" . $row['profile_pic'] . "'>
                            </div>  

                            <div>

                                " . $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'] . "
                                <p style='margin: 0;'></p>
                                <p id='grey'></p>

                            </div>

                            </a>    

                    </div>";


    }


    }

    else {

    echo "<br><p id='ynf'>You have no friends. Please add someone</p>";
    }   

**//js functions**

         function userTag(user) {  // for ajax

         $.post("includes/handlers/ajax_user_tag.php", {userLoggedIn:user}, 
         function(data){

         $('.tag_results').html(data);

         });
         }

        function textTag() { // for extracting href and placing @ and username anywhere in the post area

            $('.displayTag a').click(function(a){

            var x = $(this).attr('href');
            var y = $(this).prop('href');

            var $txt = jQuery("#post_text");
            var caretPos = $txt[0].selectionStart;
            var textAreaTxt = $txt.val();

            $txt.val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + x + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) );

            $('.tag_results').html("");

            return false;
          });

          }

    **//js code**

    $("#post_text").keydown(function (e) {  // listens for @
        if(e.which == 50)
          userTag('<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>');
        if(e.which != 50)
          $('.tag_results').html("");
      });

      $('.tag_results').hover(function(e) { //calls textTag function on hover
          textTag();
      });

  **//Empty div populated by ajax results**

     <div class="tag_results"> 

     </div>
```

**EDIT:**
I found out what the problem was, purely by accident. In the file with the php classes, `strip_tags` was used for all posts. So what I wanted to do was practically impossible with that turned on. Now it's working as it should. Thanks everyone for help! :)

Comment: Wouldn't you just put that text into an anchor tag? You need to put some code into this post, better to do a simplified example. At least the part of the code that you append the username to the dom

Comment: Sure, I'll add the code right away

Comment: What are your results? What is not working?

Comment: @Adjit  The code is OK, as far as I know, the issue is that I can't turn the username that displays after the @ symbol in the post area into a hyperlink that would link to the user's profile.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that your click event is capturing the click, because your php is dynamically creating the list element. Also your function, `textTag()` doesn't actually apply the event until that function is run, so it could be creating issues. Change your JS to -

```
$(document).on('click', '.displayTag a', function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    //other code applying href to new anchor tag in proper format
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't the php finish running before the client loads? php is on the server side

Comment: @Huangism but isn't the PHP running a query to retrieve the user list when a person types in `@`

Comment: You are right, it is an ajax call in the js, so event delegation is needed

Answer (score 0):

First I would change a little bit the PHP response in order to make it easier to get the firend's full name.

```
**//php ajax file**

    <?php

    $userLoggedIn = $_POST['userLoggedIn'];

    $userLoggedIn = new User($con, $userLoggedIn);

    $rez = array();
    $rez = $userLoggedIn->getFriendArray();


    if ($rez != ",") {

    $no_commas = explode(",", $rez);

    foreach ($no_commas as $key => $value) {

        $friend = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT first_name, last_name, username, profile_pic FROM users WHERE username='$value'");

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($friend);

         echo "<div class='displayTag'>

                        <a href=" . $row['username'] . " id='grabLink'>         

                            <div>
                                <img src='" . $row['profile_pic'] . "'>
                            </div>  

                            <div class='fullname'>

                                " . $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'] . "
                                <p style='margin: 0;'></p>
                                <p id='grey'></p>

                            </div>

                            </a>    

                    </div>";


    }


    }

    else {

    echo "<br><p id='ynf'>You have no friends. Please add someone</p>";
    }
```

Then I would modify the JS function

```
function textTag() { // for extracting href and placing @ and username anywhere in the post area

            $('.displayTag a').click(function(a){

            var fullname = $(this).find('.fullname').text();
            var x = '<a href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">'+fullname +'</a>';
            var y = $(this).prop('href');

            var $txt = jQuery("#post_text");
            var caretPos = $txt[0].selectionStart;
            var textAreaTxt = $txt.val();

            $txt.html(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + x + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) );

            $('.tag_results').html("");

            return false;
          });

          }
```

Comment: Alvaro, thanks, but unfortunately it's not working. When I click on a friend's name, the list disappears - as it should - but there's only @ in the post area. There's no name after it, neither in plain text nor as a link. I checked out the console, there are no errors. The result is the same with both Chrome and Vivaldi.

Comment: It's working now, I've edited my original question. Forgot that strip_tags was used for all posts :(  Your solution is working now. Thanks! :)